# Find the maxima and minima of $y = \frac{3}{x^2 + x + 1}$

Tags: calculus, roots, cubics

This is from "Calculus Made Easy", Exercises 10, problem 5, on page 137.

I've taken the derivative and reduced it to:

$$2x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$$

But I'm lost on finding the roots of a cubic.

Comment: Your derivative is wrong.

Comment: Your derivative is incorrect.  Write the function in the form $y = 3(x^2 + x + 1)^{-1}$, then take the derivative.

Comment: I suggest you complete the square for $p(x)=x^2+x+1$ and look at that expression to see what can be done. When is $p(x)$ minimal and what does it do for $1/p(x)$?

Comment: Woop, I think I see my mistake.

Comment: Yep, when I correctly differentiate I get $x = -\frac{1}{2}$, which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** I'm giving you the derivative and let the rest for you. With the chain rule, one has

$$\left ( \frac{3}{x^2 + x + 1} \right)' = \big ( 3 (x^2 + x + 1)^{-1} \big )' = - 3 (x^2 + x + 1)^{-2} \cdot (2x + 1) = - \frac{3 (2x + 1)}{(x^2 + x + 1)^2}.$$

Comment: Yeah, I messed up on the derivative by not reducing the -1 exponent to -2.

Answer (score 5):

It is not good to use derivatives everywhere ! Here in this problem we can use the fact that $ x^{2}+x+1 = (x+ \frac {1}{2})^{2} + \frac {3}{4} $ and we can see that it is positive for all $ x $ belonging to the real number system. Hence maxima will be attained when the denominator is the minimum which can be attained only when $ x =  \frac {-1}{2} $  you can work for the minima to in a similiar manner  it would turn out that you can find infimum=0 but there is no exact minimum.

Comment: This answer confuses me, as I don't see how you achieved the right half of the equation.

Comment: I didn't get you ? What is there to understand I used $ \frac {1}{4} + \frac {3}{4} =1 $ and assumed you know expansion of $ (a+b)² $

Comment: Okay, I see it now.  Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome bro!